# Java - While loop for menu selection (console based program)

Tags: java

*Update*
The first time the user makes a choice such as "1" the menu is displayed again. The next time a selection is made the payment information begins to cycle. After the cycling is complete and the menu is displayed again, it works as it should. Also, the first two years are output instead of just the first when a selection begins to cycle, but then outputs one year at a time as intended.

```
//create scanner object for choosing a loan, then prompt for and accept input
    Scanner choose = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice;
    System.out.println("\nType 1, 2, or 3 and press enter to see the monthly payment information for the respective loan. To end the program type \"end\".");
    choice = choose.next();

    //cycle loan 1 payment information
    //create scanner object to advance to the next year's payments

    //loop for cycling payment information
    //initialize loan principal to variable

    while (!"end".equals(choice)) {
        System.out.println("\nType 1, 2, or 3 and press enter to see the monthly payment information for the respective loan. To end the program type \"end\".");
        choice = null;
        choice = choose.next();
        if ("1".equals(choice)) {
           //calculation code
                    }
                if (j < 6) {
                    System.out.println("Press enter to get the mortgage information for year " + (j + 2));
                    choice = choose.nextLine();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Congratulations, your mortgage has been paid off.");
                }

            }

            choice = null;
        }
        if ("2".equals(choice)) {
            //calculation code
                }
                if (j < 14) {
                    System.out.println("Press enter to get the mortgage information for year " + (j + 2));
                    choice = choose.nextLine();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Congratulations, your mortgage has been paid off.");
                }

            }

            choice = null;
        }
        if ("3".equals(choice)) {
            //calculation code
                }
                if (j < 29) {
                    System.out.println("Press enter to get the mortgage information for year " + (j + 2));
                    choice = next.nextLine();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Congratulations, your mortgage has been paid off.");
                }

            }

            choice = null;
        }
    }
    choose.close();
}
```

}

Comment: The code within your `while` loop is quite repetitive. Consider creating a new reusable method.

Comment: So edited, still... ask yourself how much of all that code is *actually* relevant to your question, especially all those `println()` calls? Please read [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and severely edit the code you've posted to the absolute minimum, instead of indiscriminately copy-pasting great slabs of code. By doing so, you will often answer your own question as the code required to reproduce the problem shrinks, so the focus on what code is causing the problem increases. Likewise for us - the less code noise there is on the screen, the easier it is for us to spot the problem and help you.

Comment: @Bohemian - I agree, and have edited the post. You're point is valid, and I listened. Just as I have taken your advice, my advice to you is for your comments to include the productive advice and refrain from name calling. I'm sure that's not looked kindly upon by the community, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see three issues upfront:

1. You don't need two scanners for `System.in` stream. Remove this statement `Scanner next = new Scanner(System.in);` and use the `choose` instance.
2. If you close your input scanner as `next.close();`, it closes your input stream `System.in` as well and you may not be able read the stream again. **Make sure you close the stream only when you are completely done with your program.**
3. Use `equals` method to compare the condition in `while` as `while(!"end".equals(choice))`. Put the literal `"end"` as first argument will take care of the null value of `choice`.

**EDIT:**

Your modified code at high level:

```
    Scanner choose = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice= null;
    int j = 0;
    while (!"end".equals(choice)) {
        System.out.println("\nType 1, 2, or 3 and press enter to see the monthly payment information for the respective loan. To end the program type \"end\".");
        choice = choose.nextLine();
        if ("1".equals(choice)) {
           //calculation code
               if (j < 6) {
                    System.out.println("Press enter to get the mortgage information for year " + (j + 2));
                    choice = choose.nextLine();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Congratulations, your mortgage has been paid off.");
                }
            choice = null;
        }
        if ("2".equals(choice)) {
                if (j < 14) {
                    System.out.println("Press enter to get the mortgage information for year " + (j + 2));
                    choice = choose.nextLine();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Congratulations, your mortgage has been paid off.");
                }
            choice = null;
        }
        if ("3".equals(choice)) {
                if (j < 29) {
                    System.out.println("Press enter to get the mortgage information for year " + (j + 2));
                    choice = choose.nextLine();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Congratulations, your mortgage has been paid off.");
                }
            choice = null;
        }
    }
    choose.close();
```

Comment: I'm still working through a few of these changes. Thanks for yet another very thorough answer. Once I get everything worked out I'll likely be passing you the answer credit as before.

Comment: @Dave Do let me know, if there are still issues and you need further help.

Comment: Everything is working much better after making the changes you suggested, but I still have two small issues that I'm having trouble diagnosing. The first time I make a selection, "1" for example, the menu is displayed again. If I choose "1" again the payment information begins to display. The other is that for some reason the first two years are output at once, and then a single year is displayed with each press of enter.

Comment: @Dave Update the question with your updated program to avoid rework. Once done give me couple minutes to have a look. Let me know, once you update the question.

Comment: Question has been updated. Thanks for your dedication, Yogendra.

Comment: @Dave I see that but something is missing in the code e.g. I don't see `j` initialized anywhere before being used here -> `if ("1".equals(choice)) {
           //calculation code
                    }
                if (j < 6) {`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20145/discussion-between-dave-and-yogendra-singh)

Answer (score 1):

One bug is that String equality isn't the same as ==. You should use .equals():

```
while (!choice.equals("end")) {
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I was wondering why there was no "not equal" method in the scanner class. I see how it's done now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `choice` to `null`, so `choice != "end"` is always true.
Move the `next.close(); choice = null` to *outside* the while loop.
Also, what weolfe91 said.

Comment: It seems I have more problems than that, but that certainly helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

import java.util.Scanner;

class Main

{

```
public static void main(String [] args)

  {

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter no.1:");

    int a=sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter no.2:");

    int b=sc.nextInt();

    boolean exit=false;

    do
    {
      System.out.println("1.addition");
      System.out.println("2.subtraction");
      System.out.println("3.multiplication");
      System.out.println("4.division");
      System.out.println("5.exit");
      System.out.println("choose one!");
      Scanner sd=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("enter your choice");
      int num=sd.nextInt();
      switch(num)
     {
       case 1:
       int add=a+b;
       System.out.println("addition="+add);
       System.out.println("\n");
       break;

       case 2:
       int sub=a-b;
       System.out.println("subtraction="+sub);
       System.out.println("\n");
       break;

       case 3:
       int mul=a*b;
       System.out.println("multilpication="+mul);
       System.out.println("\n");
       break;

       case 4:
       int div=a/b;
       System.out.println("division="+div);
       System.out.println("\n");
       break;

       case 5:
       exit=true;
       break;
      }
    }while(!exit);
}
```

}